# Parsing and Transforming Nested JSON Data with Dynamic Mapping

Tags: python, json

I'm currently working on a project where I need to parse and transform nested JSON data according to a dynamic mapping scheme. The input JSON structure varies, and the mapping is specified in a separate configuration file. The goal is to generate an output JSON with the transformed data based on the mapping rules.

Here's an example of the input JSON structure (sample_data.json):

```
[{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "info": {
      "name": "Markus",
      "age": 60
    },
    "orders": [
      {
        "order_id": 59748,
        "total": 12
      },
      {
        "order_id": 59742,
        "total": 70
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

And here's an example of the mapping configuration (sample_maping.json):

```
{
  "user_id": "user.id",
  "username": "user.info.name",
  "purchase_history": "user.orders",
  "total_spent": "sum(user.orders[*].total)"
}
```

In this example, the mapping.json specifies how to extract and transform data from the sample_data.json. The "sum(user.orders[*].total)" directive should calculate the total amount spent across all orders.

I've been trying to come up with a Python script that can dynamically apply these maping rules to the input JSON and generate the desired output format. However, I'm struggling with handling the complex nested structures and implementing dynamic evaluation of directives like the one for calculating the total spent.**

Could someone please provide me advice on how to tackle this issue? Any code snippets or libraries that could make the process simpler would be welcomed.

Comment: Parse the mapping configuration for field names and then use those values to access values in the JSON.

Comment: you need to make a function that can take a string like `"user.info.name"` and split it into a list of keys to recursively get from each nested dictionary

Comment: You might also consider using an existing JSON query language that has Python library support. For example https://github.com/mwilliamson/jq.py and https://michaelheap.com/sum-values-with-jq/

Comment: Is this `[*]` custom syntax? How does it work when a key has these characters (as part of the key itself)? Any other syntax features?